# Magento Upgrade 1.12.0.2 to 1.14.3.7?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I want to upgrade magento enterprise edition from 1.12.0.2 to 1.14.3.7. So we can upgrade directly to latest version or we should go first to 1.13.x and then 1.14.x ?